# @ converted to %40 in HTTPPost request

Tags: java, android, http, https, http-headers

i m trying to send post request to webservice..
when i add special character @ in parameter it is coverted to %40.i have checked server side..they  are getting %40  instead of @.
can any one help me??
here is my code..

```
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "abc@gmail.com"));


httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
```

i have also tried this method to prevent my parameter from encoding.

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE));
```

but it raised unsupported encoded algorithm

pls help me out of this.

Comment: is the server-side decoding the url encoding properly?

Comment: I think that's how it's supposed to work... the receiving end is supposed to decode it to the `@` symbol.  Alternative explanation is that you're encoding it twice, but your posted code wouldn't do that.

Comment: can i send parameter without uncode ...???or is there any other method to send post request?

Comment: @NiravBhandari: ultimately, it depends on what the server expect. Typically, `x-www-form-urlencoded` is used when posting a request based on an HTML form. You should find out what your server expects.

Answer (score 8):

You're using `UrlEncodedFormEntity`, which will [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the content. Turning `@` into `%40` is normal with this encoding. The recipient should be able to decode that automatically, although you may have to use the correct content type for it to do so, probably `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
URLDecoder.decode("urlcontext", "UTF-8");
```

to remove any special character from the url which your passing

Answer (score 3):

You need to use something such as [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) on your server side so that you can convert the `%40` back to `@`. The same applies for other special characters.

Answer (score 3):

Use `URLDecoder.decode(url)` this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitly late for this party, but I had a similar issue. If you want to decode your url string you need to use decodeURIComponent(*url*). Where *url* is the string you are trying to decode.

W3schools does a great job of explaining it. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_decodeuricomponent